# Is there a way to tell whether two COM interface references point at the same instance?

Tags: com, identity, com-interface

Given two interface references obtained from different sources. Is there a programmatic way to tell whether they're implemented by the same instance?

A simple equality check of the interface references always fails.

---

**EDIT:** Large parts of the original question, which turned out to be an independent problem have now been moved to [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325629/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could query for the IUnknown interface and compare these pointers. All other interface pointers are not guaranteed to return the same value each time.

from [The Rules of the Component Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx):

> **Object identity.** It is required that any call to QueryInterface on any interface for a given object instance for the specific interface IUnknown must always return the same physical pointer value. This enables calling QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, ...) on any two interfaces and comparing the results to determine whether they point to the same instance of an object (the same COM object identity).